# Cross Field Validation with inline messaging in JSF with JSR 303

Tags: java, jsf-2, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

What's the best way to invoke class level JSR-303 constraints that do cross field validation from JSF and have the resulting messages get translated to a FacesMessage and be tied to a particular JSF component based on the PropertyPath in the ConstraintViolation?

[rich:graphValidator](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html_single/#sect-Component_Reference-Validation-richgraphValidator) is close, but it doesn't make use of the PropertyPath.  Perhaps MyFaces extval could get me close, but there seems to be a whole extra layer of framework on time of bean-validation, so I avoided it.

Here's a simple example:

```java
public enum Type {
    ROAD, RACE;
}
    
public class Driver {
    private String name;
    private Type licenseType;
    ...
}
     
@CarConstraint
public class Car {
    @Valid
    private Driver driver;
    private Type carType;
    private String make;
    private String model;
    ...
}

public class CarConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CarConstraint, Car> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(CarConstraint constraintAnnotation) {}
     
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Car value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value == null) { return true; }
     
        if (Type.RACE.equals(value.getCarType()) 
            && !Type.RACE.equals(value.getDriver().getLicenseType())) {

            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("Driver of this car must have a racing license")
                .addNode("driver")
                .addNode("licenseType")
                .addConstraintViolation();
     
            return false;
        }
     
        return true;
    }
}
```

Picture a form where the information about the car and the driver are input. If the Driver had a license type of ROAD and the Car had a car type of RACE, it'd be ideal to see a resulting validation message be translated into a FacesMessage which is connected to the input for license type, since the message was added to that node using the fluent API of Bean Validation.

Comment: Very frustrating that this isn't handled out of the box. I'm looking at building my own solution :-(

Comment: You make me feel better that I'm not the only one looking for this.  I was thinking about creating my own component as well, perhaps by taking inspiration from rich:graphValidator and/or using rich faces' CDK.  Earlier I started a similar discussion on the RichFaces forum: http://community.jboss.org/thread/164600

Comment: As you mentioned ExtVal can do it and we are using it for such use-cases successfully.

Comment: This is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890334/cross-field-validation-with-hibernatevalidator-works-fine-but-displays-no-error

Answer (score 0):

Our team had the same problem.  You may have a look [OmniFaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org). I used code from the validators as a blueprint to build a prototype that used reflection to call the class level validators.