# Cross field validation with HibernateValidator displays no error messages

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I'm validating two fields, "password" and "confirmPassword" on the form for equality using [`HibernateValidator`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-validator/4.0.2.GA/hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA-dist.zip/download?use_mirror=nchc) as specified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2155576/1391249). The following is the *constraint descriptor* (validator interface).

```
package constraintdescriptor;

import constraintvalidator.FieldMatchValidator;
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = FieldMatchValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface FieldMatch
{
    String message() default "{constraintdescriptor.fieldmatch}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    /**
     * @return The first field
     */
    String first();

    /**
     * @return The second field
     */
    String second();

    /**
     * Defines several <code>@FieldMatch</code> annotations on the same element
     *
     * @see FieldMatch
     */
    @Target({TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    public @interface List{
        FieldMatch[] value();
    }
}
```

The following is the *constraint validator* (the implementing class).

---

```
package constraintvalidator;

import constraintdescriptor.FieldMatch;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;

public final class FieldMatchValidator implements ConstraintValidator<FieldMatch, Object>
{
    private String firstFieldName;
    private String secondFieldName;

    public void initialize(final FieldMatch constraintAnnotation) {
        firstFieldName = constraintAnnotation.first();
        secondFieldName = constraintAnnotation.second();
        //System.out.println("firstFieldName = "+firstFieldName+"   secondFieldName = "+secondFieldName);
    }

    public boolean isValid(final Object value, final ConstraintValidatorContext cvc) {
        try {
            final Object firstObj = BeanUtils.getProperty(value, firstFieldName );
            final Object secondObj = BeanUtils.getProperty(value, secondFieldName );
            //System.out.println("firstObj = "+firstObj+"   secondObj = "+secondObj);
            return firstObj == null && secondObj == null || firstObj != null && firstObj.equals(secondObj);
        }
        catch (final Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

The following is the validator bean which is mapped with the JSP page (as specified `commandName="tempBean"` with the `<form:form></form:form>` tag).

```
package validatorbeans;

import constraintdescriptor.FieldMatch;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@FieldMatch.List({
    @FieldMatch(first = "password", second = "confirmPassword", message = "The password fields must match", groups={TempBean.ValidationGroup.class})
})

public final class TempBean
{        
    @NotEmpty(groups={ValidationGroup.class}, message="Might not be left blank.")
    private String password;
    @NotEmpty(groups={ValidationGroup.class}, message="Might not be left blank.")
    private String confirmPassword;

    public interface ValidationGroup {};

    //Getters and setters                
}
```

**UPDATE**

It's all working correctly and does the validation intended. Just one thing remains is to display the specified error message above the `TempBean` class within `@FieldMatch` is not being displayed i.e **only one question :** *how to display error messages on the JSP page when validation violation occurs?*

(the annotation `@NotEmpty` on both of the fields `password` and `confirmPassword` in the `TempBean` class works and displays the specified messages on violation, the thing is not happening with `@FieldMatch`).

I'm using *validation group* based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11810688/1391249) as specified in [this blog](http://digitaljoel.nerd-herders.com/2010/12/28/spring-mvc-and-jsr-303-validation-groups/) and it works well causing no interruption in displaying error messages (as it might seem to be).

---

On the JSP page these two fields are specified as follows.

```
<form:form id="mainForm" name="mainForm" method="post" action="Temp.htm" commandName="tempBean">

    <form:password path="password"/>
    <font style="color: red"><form:errors path="password"/></font><br/>

    <form:password path="confirmPassword"/>
    <font style="color: red"><form:errors path="confirmPassword"/></font><br/>

</form:form>
```

Comment: The reason why validation wasn't performed is because of this statement in the question "*Everything is in the same package `package validatorbeans;`*". The HibernateValidator requires the **public definition** for both *constraint descriptor (the annotation)* and *the constraint validator (the implementation class)* and I declared both of them in the same package and consequently, the default modifier **no modifier** was applied to both of them (because it's unlikely to declare more than one class or interface as *public* in the same package).

Comment: One issue however remains. It still doesn't display error messages as specified by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972933/cross-field-validation-with-hibernate-validator-jsr-303#comment8918149_2155576) comment. Does someone know the reason why it doesn't display the error messages even though the validation is performed correctly?

Comment: ok, I think you should post your solution about package-private validators as an answer.  As for the error messages it's likely a problem with the form:errors declaration which is not specified in the question.

Comment: In my first comment this a mistake (in the last line) "*because it's unlikely to declare more than one class or interface as public in the **same package***". It should have been in the same **file** and not in the same package. I really apologize to the mistake.

Comment: Are you able to get error messages to show up for simple validation? More importantly, what servlet and JSP libraries are you using? Based on your JSP snippet & on the tags, I'm guessing Spring MVC.

Comment: @jtoberon - I'm using Spring MVC 3.0.2 with Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA. The validation is all performed correctly and error messages are shown in case of annotations like `@NotEmpty`, `@Size`, `@Email` etc. The cross field validation (class level validation) as mentioned in the question **also works correctly** just it doesn't display the error messages specified (as specified within the `@FieldMatch.List({})` above the `TempBean` class).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Could you try your isValid method to be like this? (this is certainly working for me in live project):

```
 public boolean isValid(final Object value, final ConstraintValidatorContext cvc){
    boolean toReturn = false;

    try{
        final Object firstObj = BeanUtils.getProperty(value, firstFieldName );
        final Object secondObj = BeanUtils.getProperty(value, secondFieldName );

        //System.out.println("firstObj = "+firstObj+"   secondObj = "+secondObj);

        toReturn = firstObj == null && secondObj == null || firstObj != null && firstObj.equals(secondObj);
    }
    catch (final Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    //If the validation failed
    if(!toReturn) {
        cvc.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        //In the initialiaze method you get the errorMessage: constraintAnnotation.message();
        cvc.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(errorMessage).addNode(firstFieldName).addConstraintViolation();
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Also I see that you are implementing the ConstraintValidator interface with an **Object**, literally. It should be the backing object that you have from your form:

> tempBean // the one that you specify in the commandName actually.

So you implementation should like this:

```
 implements ConstraintValidator<FieldMatch, TempBean>
```

This is probably not the issue here, but as a future reference, this is how it should be.

**UPDATE**

Inside your FieldMatch interface/annotation you have two methods : first and second, add one more called errorMessage for example:

```
  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

/**
 * @return The first field
 */
String first();

/**
 * @return The second field
 */
String second();

/**
  @return the Error Message
 */
String errorMessage
```

Look inside you  method from the Validation class - you are getting the first and second field names there., so just add the errorMessage, like this for example:

```
  private String firstFieldName;
  private String secondFieldName;
  //get the error message name
  private String errorMessagename; 
public void initialize(final FieldMatch constraintAnnotation)
{
    firstFieldName = constraintAnnotation.first();
    secondFieldName = constraintAnnotation.second();
    errorMessageNAme = constraintAnnotation.errorMessage(); 

    //System.out.println("firstFieldName = "+firstFieldName+"   secondFieldName = "+secondFieldName);
}
```

Inside isValida get it, the same way you do for first and second field name and use it.

Comment: Tried and it worked, sir! Offering bounty requires some hours from now onwards, I will award it to your answer later when the system permits. Just say one additional thing please, in this method **itself** `cvc.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("Passwords in both of the fields must match.").addNode(password).addConstraintViolation();`, I have specified the error message. Is there a way to fetch the message specified in the `@FieldMatch.List({})`? No matter if there is no way to do so. It's minor thing. To me, It's a great thing to know it worked according to your answer. Thank you very much

Comment: It's all working well through out my entire application now. Thank a lot, sir!

Comment: @Tiny a pleasure I could help!

Comment: @Eugene is it possible this for internationalization ? \

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara : That just requires a message key to be specified from a localized/internationalized property file replacing the actual message such as `@FieldMatch.List({@FieldMatch(first = "password", second = "confirmPassword", message = "{message.key}", groups {TempBean.ValidationGroup.class})})` as in the question (`message = "{message.key}"`).