# How to validate a MultipartFile using HibernateValidator?

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, multipartform-data, hibernate-validator

I have a field of type [`MultipartFile`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html) in a backing bean which is bound to a Spring form (I'm using [`MultipartFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/support/MultipartFilter.html)),

```
<form:form htmlEscape="false" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin_side/Category.htm" id="dataForm" name="dataForm" method="post" commandName="categoryBean" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" id="txtCatImage" name="txtCatImage"/>

</form:form>
```

Backing Bean,

```
final public class CategoryBean
{
     private MultipartFile txtCatImage=null;

     public MultipartFile getTxtCatImage()
     {
          return txtCatImage;
     }

     public void setTxtCatImage(MultipartFile txtCatImage)
     {
         this.txtCatImage = txtCatImage;
     }
}
```

I have tried to apply annotations like `@NotEmpty` but didn't work. They ended up with an exception.

> javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: No validator could be found
>   for type: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile

I'm using Validation-API 1.0.0. Is this possible to perform a validation, if a user doesn't upload a file and press a submit button using [HibernateValidator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-validator/4.0.2.GA/hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA-dist.zip/download?use_mirror=nchc)?

Comment: Someone seems to have ask this same question before. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161215/spring-multipartfile-validation-and-conversion)

Comment: @Angel Villalain - Thanks for the link. But that question is about [org.springframework.validation.Validator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html). I used to perform validation in that way with old-fashioned controllers like [SimpleFormController](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/SimpleFormController.html). I'm using annotated controllers with HibernateValidator which that approach will not work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now I understand what you are trying to accomplish specifically. Well you could implement your own custom validation. For example, instead of implementing the Spring validator interface, implement a Hibernate `ConstraintValidator`, for a specific annotation that you define for this specific case. Check this [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-constraintannotation). In this case you could add an implementation for a `@NotNull` validator for a `MultipartFile` object.

Comment: Until now I have been familiar with [cross field validation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11890334/1391249) but not with this. Done according to the link in your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Cross field is something I still have to try, I think that was added recently to hibernate validator.

Answer (score 3):

Putting constraint on bean method checking file on emptiness worked for me:

```
final public class CategoryBean
{
  private MultipartFile txtCatImage = null;
  public MultipartFile getTxtCatImage() { return txtCatImage; }
  public void setTxtCatImage(MultipartFile txtCatImage) { this.txtCatImage = txtCatImage; }

  @AssertTrue(message = "File must be provided")
  public boolean isFileProvided() {
    return (txtCatImage != null) && ( ! txtCatImage.isEmpty());
  }
}
```