# How to implement cross-field constraints in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, hibernate-validator

Is custom constraints the way to go or is there a better approach? Before persisting the class/entity below I want to make sure.

> (!(a == null && b == null && c == null))

```
public class Foo{
   String a; 
   String b; 
   String c;
}
```

How to do this with Hibernate/Hibernate validator?

Edit:
@NotNull on fields are not good enough. They can all be only but no the same time.

Comment: there is an annotation for non-null constraints. you probably should work through a validator tutorial first.

Comment: Yes but they can all be null if they are not null(all three) the same time.

Comment: Ah, sorry for not reading properly. You could probably find useful info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972933/cross-field-validation-with-hibernate-validator-jsr-303 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890334/cross-field-validation-with-hibernatevalidator-works-fine-but-displays-no-error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to the Bean Validation standard you would need to create custom class level constraint.

If you are happy with Hibernate Validator specific features, you could use a @ScriptAssert.